# How do I visualize number of records against other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am working on road accidents dataset as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'accident_id': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4','A5', 'A6'],
                        'accident_county': ['abc', 'xyz', 'abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'lmn'],
                        'population': [100000, 6000, 100000, 100000, 6000, 9000],
                        'income':  [11200, 78000, 11200, 11200, 78000, 28000]})


accident_id        accident_county    population    income
   A1                 abc               100000       11200
   A2                 xyz               6000         78000
   A3                 abc               100000       11200
   A4                 abc               100000       11200
   A5                 xyz               6000         78000
   A6                 lmn               9000         28000
```

I want to plot graph so that I can analyze the number of accidents that happened in a particular county and what was the population and income of that county, trying to find if there is any correlation with population count and income.

The number of accidents can be found by the number of records, but I am not sure how to find count for one county and plot it against the population and income of that county.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far? Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you tried using `.groupby`?

Comment: If you have accident date, then sum number of accidents in a year, average population and income in a year too, then sort resulting chronological data according by population or income column in ascending order and plot XY graph of that relationship. You may need second order averaging of number of accidents if there will be duplicates with same population/income amount, which results in different accident count.

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding that the same `accident_county` will have the same `population` and `income` for each `accident_id`. Therefore this may suit your need

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'accident_id': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4','A5', 'A6'],
                    'accident_county': ['abc', 'xyz', 'abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'lmn'],
                    'population': [100000, 6000, 100000, 100000, 6000, 9000],
                    'income':  [11200, 78000, 11200, 11200, 78000, 28000]})

df = df.groupby('accident_county').agg({'accident_id':'count',
                                       'population':'max',
                                       'income':'max'})
df.rename(columns={'accident_id':'accident_number'}, inplace=True)

df[['population', 'income']].plot()
df['accident_number'].plot(legend=True, secondary_y=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @FBruzzesi, thank you for the reply.
when I run the above sample code, I get  " <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x2abbb1f71d0> " instead of the graph as above

Comment: This may depend upon which editor you are using, try to add the following import:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
and call 
plt.show() at the end. I will add them in the code above

Comment: It worked, but the accident number is a straight horizontal line, this is when I run with my real dataset, it has 3000 plus counties. Any idea what might be causing that.
the numbers are going exponectial on the left side unlike in the sample above with 20000,40000...

Comment: you may try to add the parameter logy=True in the dataframe plot method, this will yield a logarithmic scaling for the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby`:

```
df.set_index('accident_county', inplace=True)
df.groupby('accident_county')['population'].plot(legend=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call .groupby() and pass the name of the column you want to group on.
Like in SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(accident_id)
FROM COLUMN NAME
GROUP BY accident_county
```

In python data frame:

```
abc = df.groupby("accident_county ")["accident_id"].count()
```